# What is the correct way to set a connection string retrieved from Key Vault on a DBContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created an Entity Framework DBContext. When I did this, it placed the connection string in the following method.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("REDACTED");
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there is a warning message about having the connection string in the code. That makes sense, but from what I can gather, the linked articles in that warning message are telling me to move it the appSettings.json file. This is still insecure, as the connection string along with the database user's password will be sitting in plain text.

I have placed the connection string into a Key Vault and would like to set it at run time. What is the correct way to do this? I have thought about editing my DBContext class to take it as a property, so I could do something like the following:

```
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

Then in another class do this:

```
       var secret_connection_string = GetFromKeyVault("DbContextConnectionString")
       using(var context = new MyDBContext() { ConnectionString = secret_connection_string }) { 
            //Do database stuff.
       }
```

Is this a correct way to do this, or will this cause other problems later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a public read only property for the connection string and set it via the DbContext's constructor, and then reference this property in the `OnConfiguring` call.

Making the property read only ensures your connection string cannot be changed after the context is instantiated. While setting it in the constructor ensures it is available when `OnConfiguring` is called.

```
public class SomeDbContext: DbContext
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; } // read only property can be set in constructor

    public SomeDbContext(string connectionString)
    : base()
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }        

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);             
    }
}
```

Then you would instantiate your `DbContext` like so...

```
var secret_connection_string = GetFromKeyVault("DbContextConnectionString");
using(var context = new MyDBContext(secret_connection_string))
{ 
    //Do database stuff.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use Azure, yes key vault is one of the way. Other cloud services provided similar services for secret management.

The strategy would be to implement some sort of caching in memory the first time you read from key vault/secret provider. That way it will reduce the time to get that connection string every time next time or another part of your code want to access the same connection strings.

You can expire the cache so you can kind of reload the connection strings or secrets from the key vault if you would like, it is up to you at the end.